# Display event's venue name with JavaScript fetch and Eventbrite API

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api, eventbrite

I am creating a university project to display events that are happening in Leeds. So far I have been able to show information about the event, but I also want to show the venue name which uses a different method.

I've managed to get a venue's name through the venue ID that's found in the event information, and these are showing correctly in the console. I now want to be able to show the `venueNam`e in the HTML template of ui.js. I think it is a simple problem, I just can't figure it out!

eventbrite.js

```
class EventBrite {
    constructor() {
        this.auth_token = 'Example';
        this.orderby = 'date';
        this.city = 'Leeds';
    }

    //Load Leeds events from API
    async loadAPI() {
        const initalEvents = await fetch(`https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?sort_by=${this.orderby}&location.address=${this.city}&token=${this.auth_token}`);
    
        const events = await initalEvents.json();
    
        return {
            events
        }
    }

    async loadVenue(venueID) {
        const initalVenue = await fetch(`https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/venues/${venueID}/?token=${this.auth_token}`);
    
        const venue = await initalVenue.json();
    
        return venue;
    }
}
```

app.js

```
const eventbrite = new EventBrite();
const ui = new UI();
   
eventbrite.loadAPI()
    .then(events => {
        //Check for events
        const eventsList = events.events.events;
        
        //Print venue IDs
        for(let i = 0, l = eventsList.length; i < l; i++) {
            const venueID = eventsList[i].venue_id;
            
            eventbrite.loadVenue(venueID)
            .then(venue => {
                const venueName = venue.name;
            })
        }
        ui.displayEvents(eventsList);
    }
)
```

ui.js

```
class UI {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        this.printCategories();
        
        this.result = document.getElementById('result');
    }
    
    //Display events
    displayEvents(events) {   
        //Build template
        let HTMLTemplate = '';
        events.forEach(eventInfo => {
            HTMLTemplate += `
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">
                        <p class="event">${eventInfo.name.text}</p>
                        <p class="event">${eventInfo.start.local}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
        });
        this.result.innerHTML = HTMLTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
eventbrite.loadAPI()
    .then(async events => {
        //Check for events
        const eventsList = events.events.events;

        //Print venue IDs
        for(let i = 0, l = eventsList.length; i < l; i++) {
            const venueID = eventsList[i].venue_id;

            let venue = await eventbrite.loadVenue(venueID);
            eventsList[i].venue = venue.name
        }
        ui.displayEvents(eventsList);
    }
)
```

But note: This code is blocking. Venues are loaded once by once. To take them all, at the same time, you should look for a solution with `Promise.all`

Edit: Example with Promise all

```
eventbrite.loadAPI().then(events => {
    //Check for events
    const eventsList = events.events.events;
    let venuesPromises = eventsList.map(x => eventbrite.loadVenue(x.venue_id))
    return Promise.all(venuesPromises).then(x => {
        //x should contain all venues for the events. 

        const events_with_venues = 1 //TODO: merge events with venues
        return events_with_venues
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So how would I then use this to show the venue name in HTML template?

Comment: Im adding a new key to each event object: `eventsList[i].venue = venue.name`, so this should work `<p class="event">${eventInfo.venue}</p>`

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked!! I will have a look into `Promise.all` too!

Comment: I'm glad I helped.

Comment: Hi, sorry I've been trying to look into `Promise.all` and I'm struggling to understand it. Will I be creating this within the `eventbrite.loadAPI()` or in ui.js? Is there any chance you help me on this further?

Comment: @L.Birchall Yes, i will append my answer to provide an example with Promise.all